# Buddy.works CI: Failed to import project from private GitLab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline, buddy-works

As suggested in the very first step when creating a project pipeline on Buddy.works, I've input all required data using "Private Git server". Yet, I get an error "Failed to import " with no further details.

[image]

I couldn't find any answers searching through the net.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Is your private GitLab server reachable over the internet? It also looks like you're using an SSH url with password authentication? That probably won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so thanks to @sytech's tip, I needed to enter an HTTP URL because an SSH URL won't work since I'm using password authentication to access my repository.